# android : how to disable the animation of switch?

Tags: android, widget

Recently,I am using the widget named switch. The switch is default widget of Android Studio.The problem is that when I add  new Item with switch,its animation will run but I don't want to see it.
   I used ListView and Cursor Adapter in my project.And the switch is a item as an element of ListView.
   Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Some code block would help us to answer.

Comment: I use two activities and the first activity has a switch widget.And I expose the attribute named checked which is used to change switch's state.I use startIntent to switch two activities.Fortunately,My problem is solved.

Answer (score 9):

Calling [`jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat#jumpdrawablestocurrentstate) will disable the animation, if you call it immediately after calling `setChecked()` on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece of code from Switch widget (you can see it too - just press Ctrl and click `Switch` in your Android Studio project window):

```
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    super.setChecked(checked);

    // Calling the super method may result in setChecked() getting called
    // recursively with a different value, so load the REAL value...
    checked = isChecked();

    if (getWindowToken() != null && ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this) && isShown()) {
        animateThumbToCheckedState(checked);
    } else {
        // Immediately move the thumb to the new position.
        cancelPositionAnimator();
        setThumbPosition(checked ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

It will always show animation when visible. So you can't disable it.
But you can extend `CompoundButton` class and make your own switch widget without any animation.

Also you can copy code from Switch widget, rename it, remove animation, make some drawables and you'll get a non-animated switch.

Comment: I have read the source code of the switch but I still have no idea how to solve this problem.Therefore,I raised the problem in the website.But I have found that when I added a new item to databse,there is no animation.  Thank you anyway!

Comment: It is simple! Just copy Switch file content to your project as MySwitch and replace animateThumbToCheckedState(checked); to setThumbPosition(checked ? 1 : 0); Also you can toggle switch while it invisible.

Comment: @AlexandrShutko have you tried it yourself? When copying the source code of the Switch widget to the project you'll get a lot of compilation errors since there will be many unresolvable classes inside the source code.

Comment: Yes. I tried it. It was almost two years ago I, so I don't remember details, but there was no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having unwanted animation, when `Switch` is displayed for the 1st time, then it may help you to use `SwitchCompat` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to disable the animation of the switch by removing it from the view hierarchy, calling setChecked(val) while it's removed, and then readding it to the view hierarchy.

It's kludgey, but as far as I can tell it's the only way to do it -- you can't subclass Switch to override the setChecked() behavior because you still need to call super.setChecked() which will run Switch#setChecked() and do the animation anyway.